# Windows Store App : How to find the width of a button

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have some list of buttons that I display for showing a breadcrumb like UI. I need to know the width of each button to know how many of them can be arranged and act accordingly. But button.Width does not give me the button width. What is the way to find the width?

**EDIT**

Sample code here

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
     int width = 0;
     addHyperLinkButton(folder, out int width);   
    }

private HyperlinkButton addHyperLinkButton(Folder folder, out int width)
    {
        HyperlinkButton button = new HyperlinkButton();
        //button.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        button.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        button.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI Light");
        button.FontSize = 28;
        button.Content = new CustomTextConverter().Convert(folder.Name, 20);
        button.DataContext = folder;
        button.Margin = new Thickness(-15);
        button.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);
        button.Style = Resources["HyperlinkButtonStyle1"] as Style;
        if (!button.Content.Equals(">"))
        {
            button.Click += button_Click;
        }
        hierarchy.Children.Add(button);
        width = (int)button.ActualWidth;
        return button;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `ActualWidth` property?

Comment: ActualWidth gives 0 and Width gives NaN

Comment: Post some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Get the actual width of the button after the button has been loaded by implementing logic on the Button.Loaded event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force a render of the item, or wait for the item to be rendered. You can then use the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` properties.

To force a render:

```
HyperlinkButton button = new HyperlinkButton();
//Force render
button.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
button.Arrange(new Rect(button.DesiredSize));
```

After this you can get `Width` and `Height` of element using `DesiredSize` property.

For more info:

[UIElement.DesiredSize property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.desiredsize.aspx)

Comment: Hi Stefan,
I did the following :
    
button.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));

button.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, button.DesiredSize.Width, button.DesiredSize.Height));

width = (int)button.DesiredSize.Width;

But with this Width is always 10 regardless of what the Content property is. So I guess this is not working. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Subhankar, if it invalid value then no more other ways to get `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight` of an element before it `Loaded` event occur, I suppose.
So try to load element first and then get his `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties.

Comment: Okay... then if it is happenning in a page, what would be the event handler that gets called once all the UI is loaded?